# Scheduler Job runs in Sandbox Not in production

Tags: apex

I am new to Apex Coding and running in to production issue Scheduled class runs fine in sandbox, deployed successfully with 100% code coverage, but now the job isn't executing in production.  Scheduled with the Schedule Apex tool in UI just as in Sandbox.  The job shows up in Scheduled Jobs but nothing happens, no errors, nothing to see in Apex Jobs.

**Apex Class:**

```
public class appdevDailySnapShot implements Schedulable{
    public List<App_Dev__c> ac {set;get;}

    // implement the Schedulable interface
    public void execute(SchedulableContext con) {
        execute();
    }

    @TestVisible
    private void execute(){
        List<App_Dev_Log__c> lstADL = new List<App_Dev_Log__c>();
        try
        {               
           ac=[select Name,Assigned_To__c,Category__c,Completed_date__c,Effort_Hrs__c,Environment__c,Expected_QA_Date__c,In_Progress_Date__c,Old_Create_Date__c,Old_Request__c,On_Hold_date__c,Priority__c,Production_Release_Date__c,Project__c,Ready_for_Production_Release__c,Released_in_QA_Date__c,Released_in_UAT_date__c,Requested_QA_Release_Date__c,Status__c,SVN_update__c,Type__c,Unit_testing_DEV__c,Verified_in_Production__c,Verified_in_QA_Date__c,Verified_in_UAT_date__c from App_Dev__c];    

            for(App_Dev__c adc : ac)
            {
                App_Dev_Log__c AL = new App_Dev_Log__c();
                AL.AD_Request_No__c = adc.Name;
                AL.Assigned_To__c = adc.Assigned_To__c;
                AL.Category__c = adc.Category__c;
                AL.Completed_date__c = adc.Completed_date__c;
                AL.Effort_Hrs__c = adc.Effort_Hrs__c;
                AL.Environment__c = adc.Environment__c;
                AL.Expected_QA_Date__c = adc.Expected_QA_Date__c;
                AL.In_Progress_Date__c = adc.In_Progress_Date__c;
                AL.Old_Create_Date__c = adc.Old_Create_Date__c;
                AL.Old_Request__c = adc.Old_Request__c;
                AL.On_Hold_date__c = adc.On_Hold_date__c;
                AL.Priority__c = adc.Priority__c;
                AL.Production_Release_Date__c = adc.Production_Release_Date__c;
                AL.Project__c = adc.Project__c;
                AL.Ready_for_Production_Release__c = adc.Ready_for_Production_Release__c;
                AL.Released_in_QA_Date__c = adc.Released_in_QA_Date__c;
                AL.Released_in_UAT_date__c = adc.Released_in_UAT_date__c;
                AL.Requested_QA_Release_Date__c = adc.Requested_QA_Release_Date__c;
                AL.Status__c = adc.Status__c;
                AL.SVN_update__c = adc.SVN_update__c;
                AL.Type__c = adc.Type__c;
                AL.Unit_testing_DEV__c = adc.Unit_testing_DEV__c;
                AL.Verified_in_Production__c = adc.Verified_in_Production__c;
                AL.Verified_in_QA_Date__c = adc.Verified_in_QA_Date__c;
                AL.Verified_in_UAT_date__c = adc.Verified_in_UAT_date__c;
                AL.Snapshot_Date__c = date.today();
                AL.Snapshot_Time__c = datetime.now();
                lstADL.add(AL);
            }        
            insert(lstADL);
        }
        catch(Exception pEx){
            System.debug('**** Exception Inserting in APP_DEV_Log ****');
            System.debug(pEx.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
            lstADL.clear();
            lstADL = null;
        }
    }   
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@istest
public class appdevDailySnapShot_Test {

    static void addTestData(){
        App_Dev__c ad = new App_Dev__c();
        ad.Type__c = 'Support';
        ad.Category__c = 'appdev-SnapshotTest';
        // maybe set other properties?
        insert ad;
    }
    static testMethod void testCanBeScheduled() {
        addTestData(); // insert test data before running cron job
        Test.startTest();
        Datetime dt2 = Datetime.now().addMinutes(1);
        String CRON_EXP2 = '0 '+ dt2.minute() + ' * ' + dt2.day() + ' ' + dt2.month() + ' ? ' + dt2.year();
        Id jobId = System.schedule('AppDev Daily Snapshot - Test1', CRON_EXP2, new appdevDailySnapShot());
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertNotEquals(null, jobId);
    }
    static testMethod void testCheckResults() {
        addTestData(); // insert test data before running cron job
        Test.startTest();
        appdevDailySnapShot aObj = new appdevDailySnapShot();
        aObj.execute();
        Test.stopTest();

        // query App_Dev_Log__c for expected results
        List<App_Dev_Log__c> lstADL = [select AD_Request_No__c from App_Dev_Log__c];
        System.assertEquals(1, aObj.ac.size());
        System.assertEquals(1, lstADL.size());
        System.assertEquals(aObj.ac[0].Name, lstADL[0].AD_Request_No__c);
        // check additional properties here (must add to above query)
    }
}
```

Comment: You've swallowed the exceptions by adding a `try`/`catch` whose `catch` block doesn't actually do anything. Have you looked at the logs? You should remove that logic and just let it throw an error, then you will see very clearly when it fails and why. Also that `finally` block is completely unnecessary. The list cannot possibly persist outside of the transaction boundary. One more note, you should consider moving this logic to a `Batchable`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, How would I view the scheduled job logs

Comment: You have to have a trace flag active for the user who scheduled the job at the time it runs.

Comment: any risk of deploying to production environment during normal business operations?- Thank you

Comment: In general, no... hard to say if your org would have any such issues but it would take a particularly unhealthy org.

Comment: Deployed and its still not working- can you please guide on how to set the trace flags and logs so that I can see the error- Greatly appreciated -thanks